# How to execute one Async task one after the other?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to execute one Async task after the other. Here, if the async task 2  will be executed or not depends on the value of async task. 
Here is what i want to achieve

```
int x=0;
x=new A1( ).executeOnExecutor( AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR );
(Here x is just for the sake of explanation and making it simple, take it as a pseudo code rather than actual code) 
if (x==2)
new A2( ).executeOnExecutor( AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR );
```

According to my understanding, here the value of x will never be anything other than 0 because the condition if (x==2) will be executed before A1 is finished. 
I want that the condition if (x==2) is executed when the A1 task has finished.

Now I know that executing A2 inside onPostExecute of A1 will do the trick but my situation requires me to execute A2 independently.

Comment: So only fill in the post-execute with A2 in the cases where you want it?

Comment: @chrylis that was just one example. # There are 3-4 async tasks linked to each other. # The input values can change . The input of these async task some times may or may not depend on each other . It is not practical. I have been currently using it. And to keep using it i will have to copy paste many of them with very minor changes. Do you or do you now know how to do it without putting it inside Post Execute ?

Comment: Do you really need to execute 4 `AsyncTasks`, or do you just need to do 4 things sequentially? There is probably a much cleaner approach here than simply chaining things together in `onPostExecute`

Comment: @JeffJones Yes I know there should be a cleaner way of executing it instead of putting it inside onPostExecute and that's what i am looking for

Comment: Huh?  `A1().executeOnExecutor(...)`does not return an `int`.  It returns the `AsyncTask`, the same task that `new A1()` returns, and it returns it immediately.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike yes i know, but since showing a class variable being changed inside the onpostexecute method would have been a lengthy and complicating process.

Comment: Look at using RxJava instead of AsyncTasks - it's particularly well suited for just this sort of problem. Also, while AsyncTasks can be used without problems in a few very special circumstances, they are, in most cases, quite problematic, because they are not integrated with the Activity lifecycle.

Comment: You are stating two things. Sometimes you want second task depend on first task and sometimes not. Please explain. All logic you want serial. So for second task input you will know in onPostExecute of first. So what is the problem in adding code in onPostExecute. But if you know initially the input values of all tasks then we can suggest logic as the way you want. There is no magical thing. If you will state clearly what you want to achieve then we can suggest solution.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek How about using `AsyncTaskLoader` and `LoaderManager` instead of RxJava? will that do?

Comment: AsyncTaskLoader is an improvement over a plain old AsyncTask, but is really only appropriate for loading data, not for generalized background functionality. And it still has some issues due to the use of AsyncTask (like different behavior on different versions of Android). Also, AsyncTaskLoader isn't going to help you execute two task sequentially (or in parallel), and handle the results (or errors) all in one place like Rx.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the second asyncTask inside the onPostExecute() method of the first AsyncTask.

Comment: As you pointed out, above, the details in your question are completely in error!

Answer (score 0):

You can do your work inside one `AsyncTask`. Using `Runnable` as our parameter:

```java
private class WorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Runnable, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Runnable... runnables) {
            for (Runnable task : runnables) {
                task.run();
                publishProgress();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            //update ui
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            //done
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
}
```

And you would use this like so:

```
Runnable taskOne = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doSomeWork();
    }
};

Runnable taskTwo = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doSomeMoreWork();
    }
};

new WorkerTask().execute(taskOne, taskTwo);
```

Comment: Is runnable necessary ? Will a simple interface/listener not do?

Comment: Not necessary, but it does decouple the `WorkerTask` from needing to know about the details of the work it's doing. You could use a listener pattern as well, just make sure you only are calling UI code from `onProgressUpdate` or `onPostExecute`